# Symbolic Derivative Calculator not working - XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm doing a simple XSLT template exercise that should calculate the derivative of simple expressions with chain rule such as (x^2 + 5)^6 and should return 6(x^2 + 5) * 2x, for which I'm using templates with modes that allow to copy the inner expression and "recursively" call other templates that do the rest of the work.

As I understand, you start with the root of the tree, going down further in the match pattern for specific cases such as having a X^2 but not a constant.

I don't understand what's wrong as it's meant to be done in around 30 lines, right now it's 27 and beg for your help.

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="f"/>
        </body>
    </html>
    <xsl:template match="f">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="power/const" mode="derivar"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="power/const" mode="derivar">
        <xsl:value-of select=" power * const"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="plus/power/const" mode="copy"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="power -1"/>
        <p>*</p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select = "plus/power/const" mode="derivar"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="plus/power/const"  mode="copy">
        <xsl:value-of select="var"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="power"/>
        <p>+</p>
        <xsl:value-of select="const"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="plus/power/const" mode ="derivar">
        <xsl:value-of select="const * power"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="var"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="power -1"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show us your input and the expected output (as code).